# Append Previous State to New State in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have this app which uses the first `createAsyncThunk` to get the first page from the API, then I want the second `createAsyncThunk`, which gets the next page, to fire when the user reaches the bottom of the page and get the data in the infinite scrolling method.

```
// Gets the First 10 Posts from the API
export const getPosts = createAsyncThunk(
  "post/getPosts",
  async (apiAddress) => {
    const response = await fetch(apiAddress);
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Request Failed!");
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }
);

// Loads the Next 10 Posts
export const getMorePosts = createAsyncThunk(
  "post/getMorePosts",
  async (apiAddress) => {
    const response = await fetch(apiAddress);
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Request Failed!");
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }
);

const redditPostSlice = createSlice({
  name: "post",
  initialState: {
    redditPost: {},
    isLoading: false,
    hasError: false,
    moreIsLoading: false,
    moreHasError: false,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getPosts.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.hasError = false;
      })
      .addCase(getPosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.redditPost = action.payload.data;
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.hasError = false;
      })
      .addCase(getPosts.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.hasError = true;
      })
      .addCase(getMorePosts.pending, (state) => {
        state.moreIsLoading = true;
        state.moreHasError = false;
      })
      .addCase(getMorePosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.redditPost = action.payload.data;
        state.moreIsLoading = false;
        state.moreHasError = false;
      })
      .addCase(getMorePosts.rejected, (state) => {
        state.moreIsLoading = false;
        state.moreHasError = true;
      });
  },
});
```

My problem is that the state of the app changes to the second page and the first page contents are gone.

I know my problem is here `state.redditPost = action.payload.data` but I don't know how I can append this new state to the previous one.

I've been at this for hours and don't really know what to do anymore.

Is there any way to append the new state to the previous state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the payload data has an array of children. Like this example of response found online:

```
{
   kind: "Listing",
   data: {
      ...
      children: [
          {kind: "t3", data: {...}}
          {kind: "t3", data: {...}}
          {kind: "t3", data: {...}}
          ...
      ]
      ...
   }
}
```

So you would need to make `redditPost` be an array. Also semantically is should be `redditPosts` to denote array.

```
  initialState: {
    redditPost: {},
    ...
```

and then when you're updating it one of the easiest ways is using ES6 spread

```
state.redditPost = {
    ...state.redditPost,
    after: action.payload.data.after,
    children: [
        ...state.redditPost.children,
        ...action.payload.data.children
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is true yes but I need the redditPost to be an object since it has an "after" key which I need to get the ID for the next set of data to load.
If there was a way I could get that "after", I guess your solution might work

Comment: @Nima, I've updated the model to be more like what you want. I'm not sure what kind of data after is, but this would be how you would overwrite it. if it's the last Item index